# Do some action after takeUntil

Tags: rxjs

I'm listening to `mousemove` event until `mouseup`. I'm doing it with `takeUntil`.

**My code:**

```
    const onMouseMove = fromEvent(window, "mousemove");
    const onMouseUp = fromEvent(window, "mouseup");

    const resizePanel = onMouseMove
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(onMouseUp),
            map(
                (event: MouseEvent) => {
                    this.isDragging = true;
                    this.resizePanel(event.clientX);
                }
            )
        );
```

I have one variable `isDragging: boolean`, which I want to set to `false`, when `mouseup` occurs, e.g. after `takeUntil` in my code. It must be simple, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can't you just use `last()` after the `takeUntil`. And then replace that `map` with a `subscribe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use combineLatest on onMouseMove$ and onMouseUp$ and use a finalise subject in takeUntil.

```js
const { fromEvent, combineLatest, Subject } = rxjs;
const { takeUntil } = rxjs.operators;

const onMouseMove$ = fromEvent(window, "mousemove");
const onMouseUp$ = fromEvent(document, "mouseup");

const finalise = new Subject();

combineLatest(onMouseMove$, onMouseUp$).pipe(takeUntil(finalise)).subscribe(([onMouseMove, onMouseUp]) => {
  if (onMouseUp) {
    console.log('mouse up');
    finalise.next(true);
    finalise.complete();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try something like this

```
const onMouseMove = fromEvent(window, "mousemove");
const onMouseUp = fromEvent(window, "mouseup");

const resizePanel = onMouseMove
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(onMouseUp.pipe(tap(() => this.isDragging = false))),
        map(
            (event: MouseEvent) => {
                this.isDragging = true;
                this.resizePanel(event.clientX);
            }
        )
    );
```

The idea is to add a `pipe` with `tap` operator to `onMouseUp` used as parameter for `takeUntil`

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;

const onMouseUp$ = fromEvent(document, "mouseup");

onMouseUp$.subscribe(onMouseUp => {
  console.log('mouse up');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

takeUntil ends an observable, nothing happens after takeUntil.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, and subscribing to mouseup was something that I want to avoid.

Comment: Without subscribing to mouseUp you don't get the event. You could use combine latest on mouseUp and mouseMove.