# how to take an action after takeUntil rxjs function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, polling, takeuntil

So I am trying to have a boolean be true if the function running runs long enough to trigger the takenUntil function which is running on a timer.

Here is the code

```
start = this.http.get(environment.shochat_content_creator_set_valid_stream_start).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('Stream start'))
  );

  poll = this.http.get(environment.check_if_stream_is_active_on_mux).pipe(
    tap(() => {
        this.streamready = true;
        return 0;
      }
      ),
    catchError(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );

  startastream(){
    const endtimer = timer(60000);
    this.streampollsubscription = this.start.pipe(
      switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('Polling every 5s')),
        mergeMap(() => this.poll)
      )),
      takeUntil(endtimer)
    ).subscribe();

  }
```

essentially i want a boolean to be set to true if the takeUntil does get fired.

`timeout = true;`

I have been looking at this stackoverflow post

[Do some action after takeUntil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886276/do-some-action-after-takeuntil)

but things are not as clear as I want it to be.

Comment: why you don't add tap operator like this timer(60000).pipe(tap(() => this.streamready = true))

Comment: Cause this stuff is confusing Im not sure how I would even do that. Are you saying do something just like the above in your comment but after the takeUntil ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`takeUntil` completes the observable, so to perform an action upon completion there are a couple places you can do that:

1. in the `completion` handler:

```
this.start.pipe(
    switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('Polling every 5s')),
        mergeMap(() => this.poll))
    ),
    takeUntil(endtimer)
)
.subscribe(
    next  => console.log('handling next value'),
    error => console.log('handling error'),
    ()    => this.timeout = true    // <--- this fires after observable completes
);
```

2. using the `finalize` operator:

```
this.start.pipe(
    switchMap(() => timer(0, 5000).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('Polling every 5s')),
        mergeMap(() => this.poll))
    ),
    takeUntil(endtimer),
    finalize(() => this.timeout = true)
)
.subscribe();
```

Note: these solutions are not  *exactly* what you are asking for.  It's true they will fire when `takeUntil` fires, but they will also fire for any other reason the stream completes. I don't think that distinction matters in your case, but wanted to mention in in the context of the overall question.

As Sang Dang mentioned in the comments, you could also approach it from the angle of "*when the timer goes off* (rather than what I've mentioned thus far, "*when the observable completes*"), which you can accomplish by simply adding a `tap` to your timer.

```
const endtimer = timer(60000).pipe(
    tap(() => this.timeout = true)
);
```

Comment: adding it to the endtimer is what I will do. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [merge](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) operator and reuse your `takeUntil` condition to create a mapped `true` value when the condition (`endtimer`) fires:

```js
const { Subject, merge } = rxjs;
const { takeUntil, mapTo } = rxjs.operators;

const source$ = new Subject();
const condition$ = new Subject();

// Use the merge to work around your completed observable
const result$ = merge(
  // When your condition fires map this event to true
  condition$.pipe(mapTo(true)),
  // Your already existing pipe in wich the takeUntil lives
  source$.pipe(
    takeUntil(condition$)
  )
)

result$.subscribe(console.log)

source$.next(1);
source$.next(2);
condition$.next();
source$.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

FYI: *I am not sure if this solution works for you in the context of your application as you did not show where `timeout` is being declared and set.*

Comment: I adapted your question to a more abstract / focused level of code, to generalize the behavior and ignore the not relevant code snippets of your question. If you have problems adapting the answer, let me know and I try to translate / support.